# WebApi Formatter Insert or Add Error Attempted to access an element as a type incompatible with the array

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Experiencing type incompatible error while performing Insert or Add operation on `HttpConfiguration.Formatters.` I am trying to Add `ProtoBufFormatter`.

```js
HttpConfiguration.Formatters.Insert(0, new ProtoBufFormatter());
HttpConfiguration.Formatters.Add(new ProtoBufFormatter());
```

**Exception:**

> Attempted to access an element as a type incompatible with the array.
>   .NET Frame work: 4.5 WebApi Package: Microsoft.Owin - 3.0.1,
>   System.Net.Http.Formatting- 5.2.3, Visual Studio - Ultimate 2013, Name
>   of the Nuget package for Protobuf: WebApiContrib.Formatting.ProtoBuf

Comment: I recommend you post the full text of the error message and indicate some version information, such as WebApi version, Visual Studio, .Net FW, and the name of the NUGET you are using to get ProtoBuf into your project.

Comment: you can edit your posts at any time, for instance to add the text of your exception message.  I did it for you.  Welcome to StackOverflow.